# Close parent window if DialogResult is OK

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently i am writing an application that has a window that confirms if the user is done editing the data and let them leave a comment on the edit. The user can confirm or cancel the edit. I want to close the parent form when the child form Dialog Result is OK and refresh the data if it was canceled. The Result  is passed correctly, still it does not close the parent form.

I used ds.FormClose on other views to run the refres.

I am opening a child form whit the following code.

```
        View ds = new View ();
        ds.userID = userID;
        ds.localID= localID;

        ds.FormClosed += ChildFormClosed; // i use this line to call a function when the child form is close 

        DialogResult dialogResult = new DialogResult(); // fetches the Dialog Result 
        dialogResult = ds.ShowDialog(); // opens the view 

        if (dialogResult != DialogResult.OK) // checks if the Dialog Result is OK
            this.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (dialogResult != DialogResult.OK) // checks if the Dialog Result is OK
```

No, it does not check the dialog result is `OK`, it checks if it **is not** `OK`.

This does:

```
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
```

Comment: I will accept the anwnser in 10 minutes when i can.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you can't close the main Form and open a child Form.

If the main Form is close, the application is close and the program can't open a new child Form.

Maybe that that has no report.

Sorry for my English.